# Differences between add_post_meta and update_post_meta

Tags: database

I have a question about add_post_meta and update_post_meta.

When i am using add_post_meta:

```
add_post_meta($id, 'my_meta_key', 'my_meta_value_1');
add_post_meta($id, 'my_meta_key', 'my_meta_value_2');
add_post_meta($id, 'my_meta_key', 'my_meta_value_3');
```

It will give me something like that:

[image: Table 1]

Now when i get this data like this:

```
get_post_meta(42, 'my_meta_key')
```

I get:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'my_meta_value_1' (length=15)
  1 => string 'my_meta_value_2' (length=15)
  2 => string 'my_meta_value_3' (length=15)
```

But i can do this in another way, like this:

```
update_post_meta(42, 'my_meta_key', [
    'my_meta_value_1',
    'my_meta_value_2',
    'my_meta_value_3',
]);
```

Then in database i have:

[image: Table 2]

Now when i get this data:

```
get_post_meta(42, 'my_meta_key', true)
```

I have same result:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'my_meta_value_1' (length=15)
  1 => string 'my_meta_value_2' (length=15)
  2 => string 'my_meta_value_3' (length=15)
```

So I have a question, are either of these two ways of saving data better than the other?

Or either of these methods is better for data retrieval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```php
update_post_meta(42, 'my_meta_key', [
    'my_meta_value_1',
    'my_meta_value_2',
    'my_meta_value_3',
]);
```

Changes a single post meta, but the value is an array, and you can't put a array in the database, it wants a string for that column. So WordPress serializes it into a string and saves the result.

> So I have a question, are either of these two ways of saving data better than the other?

Yes! Serialized data is bad, it's difficult to query (sometimes imposssible), has a tiny additional overhead, and it exposes you to object deserialisation attacks.

If you want to store a list of 10 things, store 10 meta, not 1 meta with an array. If you really must do it, turn it into a comma separated list first or JSON encode it.